# Content_For on specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, discourse

I am using Discourse and I want to display few text on the category/index page only. Something like this: http://community.smartthings.com/ If you should press the "Latest" button, the banner goes away.

In my `app/views/application.rb` I have between `<%= yeild :head %>` and `/head>`:

```
<% if "categories#index" %> 
 <%= yield :test %>
<% end %>
```

And in `views/categories/index.html.erb` at the top:

```
<% content_for :test do %>
 "Blah blah blah
<% end %>
```

My issue that it works ok. But I have to reload the pages before the above works. Example: When I go to the url /categories, the text shows where I want it to. If I click the "Latest"button, the text is still there. If I refresh on the latest page, the text it gone. How to have it gone without refreshing the page?

PS: Im using it in development mode. Not production.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need that IF condition? Why not remove it and use content_for only on those pages where it is needed?

Comment: I tried that first but it shows on all pages.

Comment: Also it has to be before the closing head tag so it cant be on the page it renders.